# Verificación de correo y Cambio de clave en Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

estoy desarrollando un proyecto en Laravel 8, utilizando Fortify para manejar la autenticación (no Jetstream).

Para este proyecto, el usuario no debe poder darse de alta a sí mismo, es decir, un admin tendrá que cargar sus datos en una pantalla de mantenimiento de usuarios, y aquí viene lo que no estoy pudiendo plantear en mi lógica; al guardar un usuario en la base, necesito que se envíe un correo al usuario, con un link en donde deba cargar su password, y marcar como verificado el correo.

El circuito normal de Laravel para esto es, enviar un correo de verificación con un token, y el usuario ingresa al sistema con el password que él ya conoce porque fue el que usó para darse de alta, pero como en este caso el usuario no conoce su clave, debo poder llevarlo a que él mismo cargue una nueva clave.

¿Alguna sugerencia de como plantear este problema?

Comment: La pregunta luce basada en opiniones y eso generaría su cierre

Comment: El link del correo redirigira a una pagina donde el usuario tenga que ingresar su contraseña y verifcar el correo proporcionado?

Comment: @JuanRivera, exacto, la idea es utilizar el mismo correo que se genera para verificar el correo (que ya viene con laravel), pero llevarlo a una pantalla en donde el usuario cargue su clave, es allí en donde no se como hacerlo, o que clases sobreescribir.